# How to Enable PCIe Gen3 on Ubuntu 16.04.04

Tags: nvidia-geforce, pcie

Hi i'm look the way to force to enable PciE Gen3 on ubuntu 16.04.04 i'm look on internet but no way to enable with Nvidia Card gtx 1080

i use this string: `NVreg_EnablePCIeGen3=1`
to put on file: `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf`
rebooted!

I have tested motherbord and card on windows all is ok !
Thanks

Ps:[Link DevTalk Enabling PCIe 3.0](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/545186/enabling-pcie-3-0-with-nvreg_enablepciegen3-on-titan/)

Answer (score 0):

ok
the right way to edit `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf` is by put also the graphics card number in my case i have istalled nvidia 384 driver then:

```
options nvidia_384 NVreg_EnablePCIeGen3=1
```

and one update:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and reboot.
after for me all working !! :)